# How does angularjs prevent inline script tags from executing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, script-tag

I was interested to know how AngularJS prevents inline `<script>` tags from executing when they are included via the [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) directive.

After a template is included and the DOM is inspected, the script tags certainly exist, but they have not been executed. How are they being disarmed?

I have begun reviewing the source code but any attempt I have made to include a script tag into the DOM myself (appendChild, <strike>innerHTML</strike>, innerText, document.write, etc.) always results in it being executed.

Thank You.

Comment: Probably `ng-sanitize` is the one that is in charge of that behaviour
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/26a5779cddf70944b7548e3a6410d35237a516e5/src/ngSanitize/sanitize.js

Comment: @charlietfl - as i mentioned the script tags are definitely still in the dom - they even have an attached ng-scope - nothing looks to have been removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an artifact of the way [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite) is implemented.

To make script tags work, simply ensure that the jQuery library is loaded before the `angular.js` file.

```
  <head>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/hMoVKgkFrKFGc0HU0KpR?p=preview).

---

> if you explain more that innerHTML is enough to prevent the script tags from executing I will select your answer as correct

HTML5 specifies that a `<script>` tag inserted with `innerHTML` [should not execute.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0)

However, there are ways to execute JavaScript without using `<script>` elements, so there is still a security risk whenever you use `innerHTML` to set strings over which you have no control. For example:

```
const name = "<img src='x' onerror='alert(1)'>";
el.innerHTML = name; // shows the alert
```

For that reason, it is recommended you not use `innerHTML` when inserting plain text; instead, use `Node.textContent`. This doesn't parse the passed content as HTML, but instead inserts it as raw text.

For more information, see [MDN Web API Reference - Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

Comment: thanks @georgeawg for the answer - but my question is how is jqlite preventing the script tags from executing? not how to get the script tags to execute.

Comment: The source for `jqLite.append` is at [GITHUB jqLite.js Line #972](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js#L972). It appends script elements without executing them. On the other hand, the jQuery append method recognizes script elements and executes them.

Comment: I see the append function then calls appendChild, but it must be doing more than that because appendChild always executes the script when I use it to insert a script element - how is angularjs able to use appendChild without executing the script? Can you create a working example or fiddle in plain JavaScript that works?

Comment: if you explain more that innerHTML is enough to prevent the script tags from executing I will select your answer as correct

Comment: i see you edited the question - innerHTML will execute code if it is used on a script element itself - it won’t execute code if it is used to insert the script tag and the code together - I wonder if that distinction should be made somewhere - either way - thanks for your work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ng-include calls `$element.html(ctrl.template);` [See source on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js#L302)

The html function of jqLite then uses `element.innerHTML = value;` to insert the content. [See source on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js#L754)

And after testing - it looks like that is enough to not execute `<script>` tags.

I've created a [jsFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/jfreynik/e1o6q205/6/) - #3 is the equivalent of what AngularJS is doing and it does not execute the script tags.